# Unity - How to interrupt an ongoing animation by reversing it

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation

**Context**
I got two transform states on a GameObject, `A` and `B`. I also have two animations that transition between the two states: `A->B` and `B->A`. The animations have different animation curves. The user can change the state of the GameObject at any moment.

**What I want to achieve**
If the state is changed while no animations are playing, the animations `A->B` and `B->A` are played normally. However, if the state is changed while an animation is playing, I want the current animation to reverse. For example, let's say that the user changes the state to B, and the animation `A->B` starts playing. Then the user suddenly changes back to state A before the animation `A->B` has finished. Here I want the `A->B` animation to start reversing to state A again, not playing the animation `B->A`.

**What I currently have**
I have tried to use Unity's Animator but have found no function to reverse an ongoing animation.  I am open to using something else than the Animator but prefer not to use any external libraries.

Here is the current code I have with no reverse logic, only changing between state `A` and `B`

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class TestAnimation : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Animator _animator;

    private bool _isOpen = true;

    void Awake()
    {
        this._animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            if (this._isOpen)
                this._animator.SetTrigger("A");
            else
                this._animator.SetTrigger("B");

            this._isOpen = !this._isOpen;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: First result on Google ;) https://answers.unity.com/questions/696287/reverse-animation-by-using-animator.html

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution now. Do not know if it is the most simple one but it works. What I did was to activate the animation by playing them via script, not using any triggers or floats in the animator as I tried first.
I also created two new animation states that are the reversed version of `A->B`and `B->A`. I looked at the `normelizedTime` variable in the animator to determine if any animation was currently playing. If so, I played the reversed animation at where it ended, see the code below.

Here is the animator with the different animation states:
[image: A->B]
[image: A->B Reversed]
[image: B->A]
[image: B->A Reversed]

And here is the code

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class TestAnimation : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Animator _animator;

    private bool _toggle = true;

    private bool _isPlayingReverse = true;

    void Awake()
    {
        this._animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            var animationTime = Mathf.Clamp(this._animator.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).normalizedTime, 0.0f, 1.0f);
            bool animationOngoing = animationTime < 1;

            if (this._toggle)
            {
                if (animationOngoing && !this._isPlayingReverse)
                {
                    this._animator.Play("A->B - Reversed", 0, 1 - animationTime);
                    this._isPlayingReverse = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    this._animator.Play("B->A", 0, 1 - animationTime);
                    this._isPlayingReverse = false;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (animationOngoing && !this._isPlayingReverse)
                {
                    this._animator.Play("B->A - Reversed", 0, 1 - animationTime);
                    this._isPlayingReverse = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    this._animator.Play("A->B", 0, 1 - animationTime);
                    this._isPlayingReverse = false;
                }
            }

            this._toggle = !this._toggle;
        }
    }
}
```